# node-http-proxy not passing post data

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

*Server* listening on localhost:8080

*PhantomJS*  listening on localhost:8081

*Proxy* setup to send request to *PhantomJS* from *Server*

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ target: 'http://localhost:8081'});
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if (req.url === '/phantom') proxy.web(req, res);
    else res.end('yes yes');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Post request to  `http://localhost:8080/phantom` (Server Proxy) has "undefined" request.post

Post request to   `http://localhost:8081/` (PhantomJS) has populated request.post

What must I do to receive the post data via the proxy?

Answer (score -1):

---

Try 127.0.0.1 replace the localhost

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this answer. 127.0.0.1 is an ip address that links to localhost. Check your `/etc/hosts` file or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, it should show that `localhost` -> `127.0.0.1`
This doesn't even answer the question.